# Horizontal composition of pseudonatural transformations

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, natural-transformations, 2-categories

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be 2-categories (or bicategories, etc), and let $F,F':A\to B$ and $G,G':B\to C$ be 2-functors (or pseudofunctors, etc).
Now let $\alpha:F\Rightarrow F'$ and $\beta:G\Rightarrow G'$ be pseudonatural transformations, where the naturality square only commutes up to (coherent, natural) isomorphism.

How can we define the horizontal composition $\beta\,\alpha:G\circ F \Rightarrow G'\circ F'$?

There seem to be two valid choices, namely, the pseudonatural transformation of components (for each object $X$ of $A$) $G'(\alpha_X)\circ \beta_{FX}: GFX\to G'F'X$, and the one of components $\beta_{F'X}\circ G(\alpha_X)$. Since $\beta$ is only pseudonatural, these two choices are technically different (albeit naturally isomorphic).

Is there a canonical one, to use in definitions, theorem statements, et cetera?

Comment: In general, I think you would only have a preference if you were working in a fully lax setting and had to consistently pay attention to which direction your associators etc. are pointing; then there is a lax choice and an oplax choice. If you're working at the pseudo-level, both choices are equally canonical.